# Django creating a "sentinel" user on delete

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I do want to keep some info about removed users (like username) to show in forum posts. How can I achieve that?

So far I have this:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    (...)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True,on_delete=models.SET(get_sentinel_user))

@receiver(pre_delete, sender=User, dispatch_uid='user_delete_signal')
def create_sentinel_user(sender, instance, using, **kwargs):  
    SentinelUser.objects.get_or_create( \
    username=instance.username+" (left)")[0]

def get_sentinel_user():
    return SentinelUser.objects.latest('id')
```

However if I use that in Admin, it doesn't work because for some reason get_sentinel_user is run sooner than pre_delete and therefor the sentinel user doesn't exist yet.

Comment: For one, You are doing SentinelUsers in the create_sentinel_user and SentinelUser in the get.

Comment: I am aware of that. It's like it because i can't pass an argument from the models on_delete function call so I have to separate them.

Comment: I see now, that is a typo. The operation runs OK, there has been no error with that. Fixed.

Comment: Your sentinel users are being created how you expected now?

Comment: No, the typo is not a issue, it was not present in the code I run. Sorry for the confusion. To clarify more: The create seninel user method is not called because the process crashes at gen_sentinel_user. As I wrote in the question, for some reason the pre_delete is executed AFTER get_sentinel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your ultimate goal is to save data about the user, the [django user docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_active) suggest to use the `is_active` flag rather than deleting users. That way, you will maintain access to the user information, will not need to worry about your ForeignKey consistency, and don't have this overhead of creating a dummy user for every user that you delete.

You could then back that up by using `on_delete=models.PROTECT` to make sure you still protect the consistency of your database.

If for some reason you **have to** delete your users, I would override the `delete()` on `Post` rather than trying to use signals.

So, a sample solution could be something like:

```
def delete(self):
   self.created = SentinelUser.objects.get_or_create(username=self.created.username+" (left)")[0]
   self.save()
   return super(Post,self).delete(self)
```

Comment: "if for some reason you *have* to delete your users" <-- brave new GDPR world :)